# How to achieve the new iOS 13 card like Page/Form sheet in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I'm wondering if there's a way to achieve a view similar to the new page/form sheet on iOS 13, but on Android. Is there? I have screenshots of what it looks like before and after on iOS:

[image]

[image]

Comment: you might achieve this functionality with using BottomSheetLayout in Android